# selected value does not change in asp:Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple dropdownlist(ffg)...

```
<asp:DropDownList   ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="LightSteelBlue" Font-Size="X-Small"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged1"  Style="z-index: 102; left: 37px; position: absolute; top: 85px" Width="331px"
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

which I bind data to usind the onpageload event...

```
DropDownList2.DataSource = td.DataSet
DropDownList2.DataSource = td
DropDownList2.DataTextField = td.Columns("Name").ColumnName.ToString
DropDownList2.DataValueField = td.Columns("VendorCode").ColumnName.ToString
DropDownList2.DataBind()
```

and an  `onleselectedindexchaged` event where I try to retreive the new value like this...

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.TextChanged
        Dim url As String = "sp_menu.aspx?sp=" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue
        Session.Remove("sp")
        Session("sp") = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
        Session("spnm") = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text & " (" & DropDownList2.Text & ")"
        Response.Redirect(url)
    End Sub
```

But it always brings the first value no matter which one is clicked on the dropdownlist.
Please help!

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: If that example is correct you specified the event handler to be DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged1 but your code is in DropDownList2_TextChanged. Wrong handler being called or just a typo in the post?

Comment: The textchaged was an alternative I was trying, my code is in DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged1

Answer (score 10):

Ok... a few things...

First
`DropDownList2_TextChanged` isn't wired to your DropDownList so I can't see how that event would ever fire unless you're doing the wireup in your codebehind

Second

You say this code here

```
DropDownList2.DataSource = td.DataSet
DropDownList2.DataSource = td
DropDownList2.DataTextField = td.Columns("Name").ColumnName.ToString
DropDownList2.DataValueField = td.Columns("VendorCode").ColumnName.ToString
DropDownList2.DataBind()
```

is in your PageLoad event. Have you wrapped it in an `If Not IsPostBack`,
because if not, then you'll rebind every time, and lose your previous selection.

Comment: I did not wrap it in If Not IsPostBack because I redirect the user to a different page when they choose an item...I will try to wrap it and then get back to you.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your help. It seems I needed to wrap it in an If Not IsPostBack. Now it works perfectly. I was not aware that the post back happens even if a event has occured (in which a user is redirected to a different page.) Cool...

Comment: No Problems. Logically, what's happening is, the selected index changed, that fires some javascript with a __doPostBack to the same page. The page_load event fires, then you're SelectedIndexChanged event fires, and THEN you redirect to the next page.

Answer (score 5):

When you're databinding in Page_Load, you're essentially also resetting the selecteditem.

You should wrap whatever bindingcode that exists in Page_Load inside an
if(!IsPostBack) block.

EDIT: ...or If Not IsPostBack Then ... End If in VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use

```
DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value
```

instead of

```
DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text
```